# How to change the state from two different function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i modify state from two different function call? Following code gives me error'Maximum update depth exceeded.'

```
class App extends Component {
   // fires before component is mounted
   constructor(props) {

    // makes this refer to this component
    super(props);

    // set local state
    this.state = {
        date: new Date(),
        myQuestions:myQuestion,
        counter :0,
        activeQuestion:-1,
    };
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.begin.bind(this)
   }
    begin(){
      this.setState({activeQuestion:1})
    }

    handleClick() {
      if(this.state.activeQuestion <= myQuestion.length){
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          counter: this.state.counter + 1,
          activeQuestion:this.state.activeQuestion+1
        }));
      }


render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <div id = "myQuiz">
          <div class ="intro {{  (activeQuestion > -1)? 'inactive':'active' }}">
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
            <p>Click begin to test your knowledge</p>
            <p class = "btn" onClick={this.begin('begin')}>Begin</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
          </div>
```

What will be the right way to change state from different function call?

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing function to cllick handler. Instead you are calling the function like

```
onClick={this.begin('begin')}
```

This line is causing an infinite loop because calling this function is updating the state, which in turn is calling the render function. Change this to

```
onClick={this.begin}
```

If you want to pass the parameter to handler then

```
onClick={() => this.begin('begin')}
```

Comment: your answer works! if i was suppose to pass a parameter how can i do so , at some place they say this 'onClick={this.begin('begin')}' is the way to pass parameter . Also  i do want to update follow state : activeQuestion:1 , initially it value is activeQuestion:-1

Comment: Technically correct but if the parameter is hardcoded and also not even looked at in the handler why should you do this then?

Comment: @trixn I am just giving an example of how to pass a parameter to handler **if you want to pass**

Comment: @Prakashsharma i got it!!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in your code.

1. You override `this.handleClick` with the bound version of `begin()` in your constructor and `this.begin` will still not be bound to `this`.
2. Where does `myQuestion` come from in the constructor? Is it a globally scoped variable?
3. In your `handleClick()` you do not use the `prevState` to calculate the next state. Instead you use `this.state` which may lead to bad behavior if react batches multiple calls to `setState()`.
4. Why do you use an `onClick` handler on a paragraph? Shouldn't this be a button?
5. You have to use `className` instead of `class` in `jsx` because `class` is a reserved keyword in javascript.
6. Also the class you are trying to set will be literally the text `intro {{  (activeQuestion > -1)? 'inactive':'active' }}`. This is for sure not what you where trying to achieve.

Comment: the above code is incomplete . myQuestion is global variable. My main issue was " i wanted  to update global variable activeQuestion from different function call. it can be handle click or begin.

Comment: for number 6 i am trying to convert html/ javascript in to react . the logic i am trying to implement is  <div class ="intro {(this.state.activeQuestion > -1)? 'inactive':'active'}"> . its like if condition (this.state.activeQuestion > -1)? is true print <div class =" intro inactive">